# Visual Studio 2008 Installation Error

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Hundered of times there, I tried to install VS 2008 on my different systems already having Framework 2 installed, it failed to install.

I tried it may a times even on different systems. 
It runs 
but after Serial No. and next i see error .net framework 3.5 installation failed and there down a list of all componetns it shown which have not been attempted.

I am going to devlpe the software and without t i can;t do anything..

please help me out, please guyz...

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Also look at the install logs for more details.

Comment: Does vs2008 show any errors or is there an error in the event log of windows? Also, it happened to me several times and I ran the installation process again and it worked.

Comment: Isn't this more of a SuperUser question?

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this can be if you have downloaded the installation files from MSDN subscriptions or similar. For some reason it's not that unusual for it to not work properly and even more annoyingly, sometimes it works on one PC but not on another. One way to possibly get around it is, if you've got the ISO files, to mount the ISO file on your PC and copy all the files out of it to a local directory and then try installing from that directory which sometimes seems to work better. Or try to download the file again or if you've burned it on a disk try burning it on another disk, maybe with slower speed settings.

If you don't have a tool for mounting ISO files you can find one in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916902) kb article and it includes instructions for how to use it (note that the contents of this article is irrelevant except for just the mounting part).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem long time back. I think it's a problem with .Net 2.0 that causes .Net 3.5 to fail at installation. You need to repair .Net 2.0 first. Try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908077). Then download the offline installation of .Net 3.5 and install before installing VS 2008. It should work then.